# How to access the percent of Android download manager?

Tags: android, android-download-manager

I'm using the Android download manager in my app. How can I access the progress of the download (like the percent of download in Notification) for showing that percent in my progress bar inside the activity?

This is my method that downloads the file:

```
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//================== btn download set on click listner  ===========
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

holder.btnDownload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        dm = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownLink());
        if (!Uri.EMPTY.equals(downloadUri)) {

            Request request = new Request(downloadUri);
            request.setTitle(questionha.get(position).getQuestionTitle());
            request.setDescription("Downloading ....");
            request.setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(v.getContext(), "downloaded", questionha.get(position).getQuestionDownFileName());
            enqueue = dm.enqueue(request);
        }else {
            Log.i("Download manager","Download manager url is null !");
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: See also https://habr.com/ru/articles/735710/ (in Russian) for a solution with `ContentObserver` (I didn't check it).

Answer (score 6):

After Searching in Android Download Manager Doc I found this solution:

```
String urlDownload = "something";
DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(urlDownload));

request.setDescription("This is Desc");
request.setTitle("download picsArt");
request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "teste.zip");

final DownloadManager manager = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);

final long downloadId = manager.enqueue(request);

final ProgressBar mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar1);

new Thread(new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {

        boolean downloading = true;

        while (downloading) {

            DownloadManager.Query q = new DownloadManager.Query();
            q.setFilterById(downloadId);

            Cursor cursor = manager.query(q);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            int bytes_downloaded = cursor.getInt(cursor
                    .getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_BYTES_DOWNLOADED_SO_FAR));
            int bytes_total = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_TOTAL_SIZE_BYTES));

            if (cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DownloadManager.COLUMN_STATUS)) == DownloadManager.STATUS_SUCCESSFUL) {
                downloading = false;
            }

            final int dl_progress = (int) ((bytes_downloaded * 100l) / bytes_total);

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                @Override
                public void run() {

                    mProgressBar.setProgress((int) dl_progress);

                }
            });
            cursor.close();
        }

    }
}).start();
```

Comment: but this code works for me and update the progressbar , what you think ?

Comment: I think that you're probably wasting battery for no particularly good reason by constantly checking that value. I don't know if that's an event that you can listen on or some other way but at the very least you'd want to wait a bit after querying the DB until you do it again.

Comment: You might be able to use ContentObserver to watch for changes instead of looping:

    `registerContentObserver( 
        Uri.parse( "content://downloads/my_downloads" ), 
        true, 
        YOUR_OBSERVER );`